# SCNText won't show

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, scnnode, scntext

Before stating what my problem is I want to clarify that there are multiple answers to my question out there, unfortunately, none of them is solving my problem. Please don't mark this as a duplicate.

Now this is the code I have to create my text node

```
let textNode: SCNNode = {
            let text = SCNText.init(string: "250.9cm", extrusionDepth: 0.01)
            text.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 32)
            text.flatness = 0.2
            let node = SCNNode.init(geometry:  text)
            node.pivot = SCNMatrix4Scale(node.transform, 1/72, 1/72, 1/72)
            node.scale = SCNVector3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
            node.geometry?.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
            return node
        }()
```

This is built up by multiple different solutions that i have found and i have tried it in many different ways. However, none is working.

Here i add 1 view as a childNode and then another 3 childNodes to that child.

```
self.addChildNode(mainNode)

        topNode.position = SCNVector3(mainNode.getMidX(), mainNode.boundingBox.max.y, mainNode.getMidZ())
        bottomNode.position = SCNVector3(mainNode.getMidX(), mainNode.boundingBox.min.y, mainNode.getMidZ())
        textNode.position = SCNVector3(mainNode.getMidX()+0.005, mainNode.getMidY(), mainNode.getMidZ())

        mainNode.addChildNode(topNode)
        mainNode.addChildNode(bottomNode)
        mainNode.addChildNode(textNode)
```

As you can see in the picture below, everything is displayed properly and exactly in the location i expect. Except the `textNode` that is nowhere to be found. (note that it's the black line with hat and shoes that is main, top and bottom node)

[image]

According to the other position attributes set, the text should appear perfectly in the middle of the black line vertically and slightly to the right horizontally.

What i am missing is something i can't find in other answers. Please come with suggestions how i should approach this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SCNText Not Displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44510878/scntext-not-displaying)

Comment: Try making the text way bigger, use the scale and font size both to do it. Could be that it is ending up behind the other nodes that are covering it or that the text is just too small to see.

Comment: Setting the text font to size 32 is  not the same as a standard font size. 32 units in SceneKit is 32meters thus scaling it by 0.1 still means the size will be 3.2 metres thus this is probably why you can’t see the text. Trying scaling it more and see if that helps

Comment: @picciano Read what i wrote. I clearly stated that i have looked at other similar questions but the answers they've got doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @JoshRobbins I read that answer in another question regarding SCNText not showing up, sadly that doesn't seem to be the problem for me. I've tried multiple scaling and font sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, most likely your text isn’t showing because of the same reason as those other questions you’re sure aren’t duplicates: it’s way too big.

But I’m answering instead of voting to close as duplicate, because there’s an extra wrinkle or two worth calling out. Right here:

```
node.pivot = SCNMatrix4Scale(node.transform, 1/72, 1/72, 1/72)
node.scale = SCNVector3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
```

First, setting a `scale` and setting `pivot` to a scale transform have the same effect — both scale the node’s content, so you’re effectively applying one scale factor that’s the concatenation of the two transforms. (Also, as of these calls, `node.transform` is identity, so the first line is equivalent to `SCNMatrix4MakeScale` with the same factor.)

Second, as explained in [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42613002/957768), the `pivot` property applies the *inverse* of the transform you provide to the node’s content. Your transform is a reduction in scale, so the transform applied is the inverse of that: an increase in scale.

(The [documentation for `pivot`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408044-pivot) is rather unclear on the inverse transformation part. Maybe if you [tell Apple about it](http://bugreport.apple.com) they’ll fix that doc.)

Putting it together: you’re scaling a 32 “point” text node down to 1/10x, then up to 72x. That’s the same as scaling it to 7.2x, or just using a 230 “point” font to start with.

And as [noted elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44829260/957768), “point” sizes for fonts are actually meters in SceneKit+ARKit, so you probably have skyscraper-size letters floating somewhere above and to your right (if they’re not invisible because they’re beyond clip depth). Hope you brought climbing gear...

Comment: Ah i see, great explaination. it was from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41066865/how-to-place-text-in-the-certain-position-when-using-scenekit that i used 1/72 pivot, but maybe i misunderstood what he wrote. But i figured as much as my text was either to big or to small, i just couldn't figure out which one and to what degree in size it was. But you gave a great explanation of  pivot, transform and scale which i have had a bit of a problem with. and even tho i already solved the problem, yours are the correct one.